# How do you write to a Unix terminal from a cmd session created by Runtime.exec?

Tags: java, terminal

I have a CmdProc object in java which uses a Runtime.exec-created session and handles the StdIn, StdOut and Error streams. It works fine on Linux, AIX and Windows. I can send most OS commands and process the results, including responding to their prompts.

However, when I send an "su" command it expects input from the TERMINAL, not from StdIn so my response to its' prompt is ignored.

Any idea how I write something that "appears" to have come from the terminal?

Comment: is using sudo with the -S command an option? sudo -S will read the PW from stdin

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately these are prod boxes and the userid I am using to run the java program is not allowed to sudo. If it could then I could just sudo su - newuser. Also I am hoping to set the session to the new userid, not just run a single command as the code to pre-pend "sudo -S" to every command might get a bit complex in the middle of a generic submitter. But definitely a valid suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: what about setting the +s bit for you application giving it automatically super user rights?

Comment: Again, thanks for the effort. Not sure about that one. I am running the application as "java -jar JarFile". If the sticky bit has to go on java.exe I don't think our Unix SysAdmins would like that? Can it work on the jar file?

Comment: you could create a startup script, set +x and +s, then call the script instead of jave (script contains java -jar JarFile)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again Nidhoegger.
The answer seems to be using send/expect. It does mean a specific installation on the box - which I was hoping to avoid - but I can create the expect script on the fly, store it in /TMP and then execute it, passing the de-crypted password as a parameter. Then delete the script again. It is working so perhaps I can find the time to dig into the send/expect source code (in Tcl) and see if there is some terminal handling that can be ported to java.
Thanks for your efforts.